# how ot import jkqtplotter to my qt programer?

Tags: qt

i download the JKQtPlotter-4.0.0 from internet, but i don't know how to import it to my programer.
i try to follow the course, but i fails.

i add

```
   # include JKQTPlotter source headers and link against library
   DEPENDPATH += ./lib  ./qmake/staticlib/jkqtplotterlib
   INCLUDEPATH += ./lib
   CONFIG (debug, debug|release) {
       LIBS += -L./qmake/staticlib/jkqtplotterlib/debug -ljkqtplotterlib_debug
   } else {
       LIBS += -L./qmake/staticlib/jkqtplotterlib/release -ljkqtplotterlib
   }
```

to the qt's profile and than buid it.
finally, i get three errors:

1. cannot find -ljkqtplotterlib_debug
2. collect2.exe:error:Id returned 1 exit status
3. [Makefile.Debug:72:debug/JK.exe] Error 1

Comment: Are these the [instructions](http://jkriege2.github.io/JKQtPlotter/page_buildinstructions__q_m_a_k_e.html) you're following?